# Code first EntityConfiguration

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

Is it possible to modify / replace an entity configuration in a context that is being inherited in a different context?

Example:  I have Context in a project called Data.Access in a solution called Framework.  Its OnModelCreating function adds entity configurations thusly:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
   // TestEntityConfiguration is the configuration of an entity named TestEntity in the Framework solution
   modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TestEntityConfiguration());

   // multiple other configurations...
}
```

In another solution called FrameworkConsumer, I have a Local.Data.Access project that has a Context class which extends Context from Data.Access in the Framework solution.  Its OnModelCreating function looks like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   // Adds all the configurations from the Context in Data.Access in the Framework solution
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   // Other configurations local to the extended context go here...
}
```

My question is this.  In the Local.Data.Access project in the FrameworkConsumer solution, if I wanted to add extra configuration settings or a different configuration for TestEntity, how can this be accomplished or can it be done?  I've tried adding another configuration however, I get errors stating that this Entity (TestEntity) has already been configured.  For now, my solution to add extra configuration was to use Database.ExecuteSqlCommand in the Dispose function in Local.Data.Access Context class.  Not elegant, but it works.  Any ideas / advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put that configuration in another virtual method, that you can override if you need to change it. For instance:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
   // multiple other configurations...
   SpecialConfigurations(modelBuilder);    

}

protected virtual void SpecialConfigurations(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
   // TestEntityConfiguration is the configuration of an entity named TestEntity in the Framework solution
   modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TestEntityConfiguration());

   // multiple other configurations...
}
```

And then override the SpecialConfigurations method.